# Hierarchical data structures with vectors in c++, that can be traversed bottom-up and top-bottom

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++11, iterator, multimap

I have a hierarchical structures of few levels. I have the following:

```
RawSheet = vector<Country>
Country = vector<City>
City = vector<Building>
```

and the classes besides the vectors contain some other useful stuff. The problem is
I can only go top to bottom in the whole structure, that is, starting from a RawSheet
I can get its countries, and then for each Country I can get the cities, and for each City
I can get its buildings. But I also need to be able to do this: given a Building, get its City,
then for the City get its Country, and finally get the RawSheet for that country. What I have
now is basically a tree with links top-bottom, but not bottom to top. Can you suggest me ways to
do this, and then also how do I manage those links? For example each city can keep a reference
to a country, its own. Same for the others... Keep a reference to your parent.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, Buildings should have a reference to its City and so on. Managing them is just like any other reference, just keep up with them and free unused memory when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a base class `Layer` that has a pointer to a parent layer and a name that you can print. Then you can define all the layers in your hierarchy by simply inheriting from this `Layer` and using the new C++11 inheriting constructor feature to avoid code repetition (in C++98 you would have to define the constructor in every concrete layer).

I would not store the children inside the layer but in a `std::multimap<Layer*, Layer*>` instead, so that you can use the convenient member function `equal_range` to get all children of any concrete layer inside your application (I called this data structure `Atlas`).

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Layer
{
public:
    explicit Layer(std::string n, Layer* p = nullptr): name_(n), parent_(p) {}
    std::string name() { return name_; }
    Layer* parent() { return parent_; }
private:
    std::string name_;
    Layer* parent_;
};

// inheriting constructrors (C++11 only, retype constructors for C++98)
class City   : public Layer { using Layer::Layer; };
class Country: public Layer { using Layer::Layer; };
class Planet : public Layer { using Layer::Layer; };

typedef std::multimap<Layer*, Layer*> Atlas;

int main()
{
    Planet Earth("Earth");

    Country USA("United States of America", &Earth);
    Country FRA("France", &Earth);

    std::vector<City> USA_cities = { City("Los Angeles", &USA), City("New York", &USA) };
    std::vector<City> FRA_cities = { City("Bordeaux", &FRA), City("Paris", &FRA) };

    Atlas a;

    a.insert(std::make_pair(&Earth, &USA));
    a.insert(std::make_pair(&Earth, &FRA));

    for (auto& city: USA_cities)
        a.insert(std::make_pair(&USA, &city));

    for (auto& city: FRA_cities)
        a.insert(std::make_pair(&FRA, &city));

    auto countries = a.equal_range(&Earth);
    std::cout << "Countries on planet " << countries.first->first->name() << " :\n";
    for (auto it = countries.first; it != countries.second; ++it) {
         auto country = it->second;
         std::cout << country->name() << " (located on planet " << country->parent()->name() << "), with cities:\n";
         auto cities = a.equal_range(country);
         for (auto jt = cities.first; jt != cities.second; ++jt) { 
              auto city = jt->second;
              std::cout << "     " << city->name() << " (located in country " << city->parent()->name() << ")\n";
         }
         std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7365457a5a2b88df7459566644bcd0a1-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc) with the following output:

```
Countries on planet Earth :
United States of America (located on planet Earth), with cities:
     Los Angeles (located in country United States of America)
     New York (located in country United States of America)

France (located on planet Earth), with cities:
     Bordeaux (located in country France)
     Paris (located in country France)
```

As you can see, you can iterate up and down this hierarchy.

You can critique this solution on several points. There is no enforcement on the class hierarchy: a `Planet` can have a list of `Cities` without intermediate `Country` layer, etc. You could enforce such things through either compile-time checking or through runtime type information. This is a tradeoff between flexibility and safety.

There is also no `virtual` destructor in the base class `Layer`. As long as you don't try to delete any concrete layer objects through `Layer*`, there is no problem with that. There are also no smart pointers because all the `Layer*` are non-owning pointers. If you ever want to move or copy buildings around (it happens sometimes), you could extend it easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this problem. I'm just exposing one.

You can encapsulate each element of the container with a reference to the container. Something like:

```
class Country;

class City {
public:
    City(Country& c): country(c) {
    }

private:
    string      name;
    size_t      population;
    Country&    country;
};

class Country {
    string          name;
    vector<City>    cities;
};
```

You could use a pointer instead a reference to container, of course. But if you want to force each city is owned by just one Country, use a reference. In this case, you have to supply a constructor to City class, as seen in the example.

Extend this sample to the other levels of the hierarchy is easy too.